# Implementing "Full-Bin Packing" Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, bin-packing

I'm working on a project which is implementing the "**Full-bin packing**" algorithm in Java. This algorithm name comes from **Decision A-Level Maths** - but I can't find much information about it on the internet.

The algorithm is described as follows:

- Use observation to find items that will fill a bin. Pack those items first.
- Use the first-fit algorithm (which I have already written the methods for) to pack the rest of the items.

So I had 2 questions:

1. Is this the same as what is called "**best-fit**" algorithm?
2. How can I implement this in a program? (specifically, what is the best way of finding combinations that will fill a bin?)

In the case of my program, the items are going to be numbers and both the maximum number of numbers and the number of bins is going to be limited to 6.

I haven't actually written any code yet as I'm not sure about how to implement it in the first place - but I edited the first post to show one way I was thinking of doing it.

**Edit -**
Let's say the 6 numbers I have are: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.

The way I thought of it was to first sort the numbers into decreasing order, and then having 2 loops to try every possible combination to see if any of them fill a bin (e.g. 1 & 2, 1 & 3, 1 & 4, 1 & 5, 1 & 6 and then 2 & 3, 2 & 4 and so on), would this be a good way of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: This sounds a lot like the `0/1 Knapsack Problem`.

Comment: I haven't actually written any code yet as I'm not sure about how to implement it in the first place - but I edited the first post to show the way I was thinking of doing it.

Comment: Try something. If it doesn't work, try something else. If you get stuck, come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @christopher If you try to solve Bin packing ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem ) with Repetitive 0/1 Knapsack , it will fail for some test cases.

Comment: @shiva thanks for the update!